# what does this prototype do?

Tags: javascript

Is it making a new  version of the Number function and calling it something else?  Is there a better way to write this?

```
Number.prototype.clamp = function(min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
};
```

Is it the same as

```
Number.prototype.NumberToMystring = function(n) {
  return n.toSTring();
};
```

then NumberToMystring(5) will return "5" but as a string

Comment: That `NumberToMystring()` function doesn't make any sense. It is a method of all Number objects, but it *ignores* the number that it is called on. For example, you could call it with `(10).NumberToMystring(20)`, and the function wouldn't do anything at all with the `10` it was called on. It's the same as if you'd called `(20).toString()`.

Comment: It sounds like you may be kind of guessing about what this `.prototype.` business is all about, yes? In that case, the best thing would be to read up on them: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+prototypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No NumberToMystring is not the same as clamp.

Clamp has a different objective and so is NumberToMystring. Clamp ensures the number is within a range where as the later is a conversion operator.

Usage of clamp is

```
var x = (5).clamp(0, 255); return 5


Number.prototype.clamp = function(min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
};
```

If you see this prototype. You will have a this object in the return statement. Which is nothing but the Number against which you called the clamp in our case it's 5.

To understand why it's happening like this you have to understand whole lot of concepts start from Execution context , Scope and then visit prototype.

Try to change the clamp function like this and see what it returns. This will help you understand why your JS fiddle code is not working.

```
Number.prototype.newclamp = function(min, max) {
  return this;
};
```

This will return the Number object. If you analyze the scope chain during this call then you will find 5 in its scope and thus 5 will be returned when any operation is performed

```
var y = 5;
var z;

z = y.newclamp();
z.toString() // return 5;


Number.prototype.NumberToMystring = function(n) {
  return n.toSTring();
};
```

In this particular prototype, you are only using the argument that is passed when you call the prototype. That's why NumberToMystring(5) returns "5" taking 5 as an argument

For understanding prototypes , scope chain and Execution contexts have a look at this site.
http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-3-this/

Comment: can you add your other answer to plesae

Comment: and how do I call clamp I tried var x = Number.clamp(10); but i get an error

Comment: @Hello-World: You have to pass two arguments to clamp. var x = (5).clamp(0, 255); return 5

Comment: Not quite: `clamp()` is a method of all Number objects. For example, you can call it like this: `(100).clamp(5,10)`.

Comment: @Hello-World: Ok now i understood your question. I will update the answer in a min.

Comment: @Hello-World: Sorry for the delay. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object Object; all objects inherit methods
and properties from Object.prototype Object.prototype, although they may be overridden
(except an Object with a null prototype, i.e. Object.create(null)). For example, other
constructors' prototypes override the constructor property and provide their own toString
methods. Changes to the Object prototype object are propagated to all objects unless the 
properties and methods subject to those changes are overridden further along the prototype   chain.

[SEE HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: OP does not use `Object.prototype`